Analogue of the Vcl.Controls.CM_DESIGNHITTEST message in FireMonkey
Good day.
What is the analogue of the Vcl.Controls.CM_DESIGNHITTEST﻿ message in FireMonkey?
I need to have a specific section in my FmxControl that receive mouse messages at Design-Time.
